# All addresses to go to a single page (catch-all route to a single view) in Python Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to alter the [Pyramid hello world example](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/index.html) so that any request to the Pyramid server serves the same page. i.e. all routes point to the same view. This is what iv got so far:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

def hello_world(request):
    return Response('Hello %(name)s!' % request.matchdict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('hello', '/*')
    config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

All iv done is change the line (from the hello world example):

```
    config.add_route('hello', '/hello/{name}')
```

To:

```
    config.add_route('hello', '/*')
```

So I want the route to be a 'catch-all'. Iv tried various variations and cant get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax for the catchall route (which is called "traversal subpath" in Pyramid) is `*subpath` instead of `*`. There's also `*traverse` which is used in hybrid routing which combines route dispatch and traversal. You can read about it here: [Using *subpath in a Route Pattern](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hybrid.html#using-subpath-in-a-route-pattern)

In your view function you'll then be able to access the subpath via `request.subpath`, which is a tuple of path segments caught by the catchall route. So, your application would look like this:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

def hello_world(request):
    if request.subpath:
        name = request.subpath[0]
    else:
        name = 'Incognito'
    return Response('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Configurator() as config:
        config.add_route('hello', '/*subpath')
        config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')
        app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8081, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Don't do it via custom 404 handler, it smells of PHP :)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what im looking for! I looked over that section of the docs a few times but im just not that used to the terminology so it didn't click. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could create a custom error handler (don't remember off the top of my head but it was in the Pyramid docs) and capture HTTP 404 errors, and redirect/render your catch-all route from there.

The link I'm thinking of: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/narr/hooks.html

I've done something like this:

```
from pyramid.view import (
    view_config,
    forbidden_view_config,
    notfound_view_config
    )

from pyramid.httpexceptions import (
    HTTPFound,
    HTTPNotFound,
    HTTPForbidden,
    HTTPBadRequest,
    HTTPInternalServerError
    )

import transaction
import traceback
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#region Custom HTTP Errors and Exceptions
@view_config(context=HTTPNotFound, renderer='HTTPNotFound.mako')
def notfound(request):
    if not 'favicon' in str(request.url):
        log.error('404 not found: {0}'.format(str(request.url)))
        request.response.status_int = 404
    return {}
```

I think you should be able to redirect to a view from within there.