# Changing view or route after the request has been started in Pyramid

Tags: python, web, pyramid

I have a situation where if the user visits any route on my Pyramid application I would like to serve them one particular view. Basically "force" them to a single page. A redirect would be fine too.

Is there something in Pyramid to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381041/all-addresses-to-go-to-a-single-page-catch-all-route-to-a-single-view-in-pytho

Comment: I actually read that question first. It doesn't apply to this situation. I don't want a catch all route. I want conditionally, sometimes, route to a particular view, but from all other, valid routes.

Comment: Update your question to better reflect your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to view this as a permission/security problem then you can deal with it by adding appropriate permissions/ACLs to your application and then handling the issue in a forbidden view by likely returning a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
return HTTPFound(location=request.route_path('some_route_name'))
```

or `raise HTTPNotFound` and similar errors. Check [this link](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/narr/hooks.html) if you want to extend default error view to change template or something else